# “Select Python Interpreter” button not showing (Pycharm)

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

In one of my PyCharm projects, it doesn't show the "Select Python interpreter" button on the lower right-hand side. Here is how it's supposed to be:

[image]

However, it's not there. I need it to add an interpreter for my Python project. How do I get this button back (or how to add an interpreter in PyCharm)?

PS: I looked this up, but they told me to go to settings and do it there, but I think they removed this feature in PyCharm 2021.1.

Comment: This feature was not removed. Try right-clicking on the bottom toolbar and selecting "Python Interpreter" from the drop-down.

Comment: Did that, but the "Python Interpreter" option was already ticked, and reticking didn't do anything.

Comment: Did contact PyCharm support? If not - sent them `idea.log` from **Help | Show Log in ...** at pycharm-support@jetbrains.com

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: @TkinterLover Please post an answer with your solution, so that others with the same issue who will stumble upon your question can use it. Self-answering is welcome in this community.

Answer (score 2):

### Root cause

This happens when there is no `.idea/<project-name>.iml` file in your `.idea/` settings folder for PyCharm or IntelliJ IDEA.
In most cases, this file is modified by VCS.

### Workaround

Close your project in PyCharm
Create a backup of your `.idea/` folder
Remove `.idea/` folder
Re-open your project
Your project will be re-initialised. You could then copy some of the settings files from your backup to your new `.idea/` folder.

***The solution to the problem is taken from the JetBrains issue tracker forum***

source [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48492)